# Parent window visibility on child popup

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, applet, popup

I have this problem when opening a new child window in IE8 in Windows7, but reported on any IE version and Windows environment.  Below are the steps to recreate issue:

1. Ok so first I open Windows Notepad application.
2. Then I open a new browser that loads a Java Applet.  So now the Notepad application is in back of this new browser window.
3. From the Applet I use Javascript which opens a new child window using the usual "window.open(...)".

Problem is that when child window is opened, the Notepad window places itself on top of the parent Java Applet window.

Why does that behavior occur?  I mean is there a way to prevent that from happening?  Using Javascript maybe?  I have no control of the Notepad application, so not sure how to fix this.

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: *"is there a way to prevent that from happening?"*  **Don't use pop-ups.**

Answer (score 0):

Just want to mention that setting the focus using Javascript on top worked for me.